# Cannot access pymc trace

Tags: curve-fitting, pymc

I am new to pymc and trying to access data inside a trace, but I run into the following error:

> raise KeyError(key)
>
> KeyError: 'α'

I cannot figure out why it happens. Even in a simple code such as the one below, I get this error, but have been unable to find a solution to it.

```
import pymc as pm
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(1)
N = 100
alpha_real = 2.5
beta_real = 0.9
eps_real = np.random.normal(0, 0.5, size=N)
x = np.random.normal(10, 1, N)
y_real = alpha_real + beta_real * x

y = y_real + eps_real

with pm.Model() as model_g:
  α = pm.Normal('α', mu=0, sigma=10)
  β = pm.Normal('β', mu=0, sigma=1)
  ϵ = pm.HalfCauchy('ϵ', 5)
  μ = pm.Deterministic('μ', α + β * x)
  y_pred = pm.Normal('y_pred', mu=μ, sigma=ϵ, observed=y)
  trace_g = pm.sample(2000, tune=1000,cores=1)

alpha_m = trace_g['α'].mean()
beta_m = trace_g['β'].mean()
```

I have read that this error arises when the variable i am trying to call in the last two lines is not inside the trace.Apparently, you can sometimes fix this by declaring a deterministic variable, but since I wanto to find data on the fitted alpha and beta distributions, I don't really see how this is possible.

Please help me